# What is the code { [s: string]: boolean } in the Angular Code block?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and was going through various scenarios and examples. One of the examples I came across is the following custom validator:

```
  confirmationValidator = (control: FormControl): { [s: string]: boolean } => {
    if (!control.value) {
      return { required: true };
    } else if (control.value !== this.validateForm.controls.password.value) {
      return { confirm: true, error: true };
    }
    return {};
  };
```

In the above, what is the code `{ [s: string]: boolean }` mean? Is it checking for the input value or it is used for something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{ [s: string]: boolean }` uses an [index type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types), saying that `confirmationValidator` returns an object with properties keyed by strings whose values are booleans.

Answer (score 1):

This is Typescript. The `{ [s: string]: boolean }` declares the *return type* of the arrow function.

This is how Typescript describes the type of objects that can have any strings as keys, and booleans as values.

It's a bit of a shame, as a type could have been used that listed all the optional keys (like required, confirm, error). It would seem that that would give more of the benefits of Typescript.